# Scipy: fitting a spline to a custom function instead of points

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I was wondering if there was a method to fit a Spline directly to a function instead of points. Currently I'm manually creating the points from the function. Following is the code I use (simplified version)

```
    def get_fit_function(self, function, test_range, k=3, **fArgs):

        x = np.array(test_range)
        y = np.array([function(p, **fArgs)
                      for p in x])  # my function
        u = UnivariateSpline(x, y, k=k)
        print('avgError', u.get_residual()**0.5 / len(x_values))
        return u
```

I couldn't find anything in the scipy documentation. Does anybody know if such a method exists? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You need to sample your function on some grid. If you have more information than just points, you could use that, too. For one, if you can compute derivatives, you can use those too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The thing is, I'm trying to speed up my code. The function in question results from an implicit equation so the calculation with spline is 500-1000 times faster (`%timeit`) with a minimum error.